# Read numeric input as string R

Tags: r

So, i have this input csv of the form,

```
id,No.,V,S,D
1,0100000109,623,233,331
2,0200000109,515,413,314
3,0600000109,611,266,662
```

I need to read the No. Column as it is(i.e., as a character). I know i can use something like this for that:

```
data <- read.csv("input.csv", colClasses = c("MSISDN" = "character"))
```

I have a code that i'm using to read the csv file in chunks:

```
chunk_size <- 2
con  <- file("input.csv", open = "r")
data_frame <- read.csv(con,nrows = chunk_size,colClasses = c("MSISDN" =   "character"),quote="",header = TRUE,)
header <- names(data_frame)
print(header)
print(data_frame)
if(nrow(data_frame) == chunk_size) {
repeat {
data_frame <- read.csv(con,nrows = chunk_size, header = FALSE, quote="")
names(data_frame)<-c(header)
print(header)
print(data_frame)
if(nrow(data_frame) < chunk_size) {
  break
}
}
}

close(con)
```

But, here what the issue i'm facing is that, the first chunk will only read the No. Column as a character, the rest of the chunks will not.

How can i resolve this?

PS: the original input file has about 150+ columns and about 20 Million rows.

Comment: Why are you reading it in chunks?

Comment: Your final `read.csv` does not use `colClasses` like the other two.

Comment: @Remko in the final read.csv i cant add colClasses because i've set header=false in that statement.

Comment: One straight forward solution would be using `readLines` to read the file as string and `split` to get the cols ...

Comment: @holzbenCan u please elaborate, i'm fairly new to R

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the column type *colClasses* in the read.csv() inside the *repeat* procedure.
You no longer have the header so you need to define an unnamed vector to specify the *colClasses*.
Let's say the size of colClasses is 150.

`myColClasses=rep("numeric",150)
myColClasses[2] <- "character"
repeat {
   data_frame <- read.csv(con,nrows = chunk_size, colClasses=myColClasses, header = FALSE, quote="")`
    ...

Comment: the input i've provided is just a sample. The original file contains about 150+ columns. It would be very difficult to employ your solution then. Is there any alternate way?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the data as string with `readLines` and split it:

```
fileName <- "input.csv"
df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(readLines(fileName), ",")[-1]) # skipping headlines
colnames(df) <- c("id","No.","V","S","D") #adding headlines
```

or the direct approach with `read.csv`:

```
fileName <- "input.csv"
col <- c("integer","character","integer","integer","integer")
df <- read.csv(file = fileName,
               sep = ",", 
               colClasses=col, 
               header = TRUE, 
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: As i've already mentioned in the question, the input file contains about 150+ columns and manually putting datatypes for all the column headers is very difficult.

Comment: in my first code snippet you don't need to to that. The correction of the column names (third line) can be done automatically as well eg. use readLine